# How to Change Cursor on Hover at Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Add Hand Cursor on hover at Image.

```
<img src="img/buy.png" style="height: 100px;">
```

Anyone can help me here?

Answer (score 29):

Use CSS:

```
img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
img {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

This means that when you hover over the image your cursor will be a pointer.